# What type of fine-tuning does the OpenAI API use?

Tags: open-ai, gpt, fine-tuning

They have [instructions](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning) on how to fine-tune. But I'm not clear on the type of fine-tuning that is done. Maybe this is mentioned somewhere. I would imagine it's some type of PEFT to avoid catastrophic forgetting. Plus fine-tuning the whole model for individual customers seems unlikely also.